# roslaunch file using rosparam

Tags: roslaunch, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to write a roslaunch file which opens a few nodes with unique ip addresses which are provided in a yaml file.  If I wanted to start each one using terminals for each I would type it in as follows:

rosrun foo_pkg foo_node 1 192.168.100.10
rosrun foo_pkg foo_node 2 192.168.100.20

I want to be able to open them all in one launch file:

**FIRST TRY SIMPLY CODING INTO LAUNCH FILE:**

```
     <launch>
       <node   name="FOO1"
               pkg="foo_pkg"
               type="foo_node"
               args="1 192.168.100.10"
               output="screen"/>
       <node   name="FOO2"
               pkg="foo_pkg"
               type="foo_node"
               args="2 192.168.100.20"
               output="screen"/>
     </launch>
```

This didn't work, I guess I can't put the arguments in this way but don't know how to put them in correctly.

**In the end I want it to get these values from a launch file like below:**

```
     ip:  
       board1:  
         num: 1  
         address: '192.168.10.10'  
       board2:  
         num: 2  
         address: '192.168.10.20'
```

So my main question is ... **HOW CAN I USE THE ROSPARAMS INSIDE THE ROSLAUNCH FILE TO PROPERLY LAUNCH THEM?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189225/roslaunch-file-using-rosparam/) by [vbplaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/15116/vbplaya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you're on the right track, but you've misunderstood the XML syntax of launch files.

Try:

```
<launch>
  <node   name="FOO1"
          pkg="foo_pkg"
          type="foo_node"
          args="1 192.168.100.10"
          output="screen"/>
  <node   name="FOO2"
          pkg="foo_pkg"
          type="foo_node"
          args="2 192.168.100.20"
          output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vbplaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/15116/vbplaya/) on 2014-08-07**:
Actually, I already had it exactly like this ... I just don't know how to put the greater than and less than symbols in message without it thinking it is actual xml code to execute.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-07**:
You question was completely unclear about that.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-07**:
You say that this launch file "didn't work." There are serveral hundred things that might cause it to not work. Can you edit your question to include the exact command and the exact output from the command?

**Comment by [vbplaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/15116/vbplaya/) on 2014-08-07**:
It turns out my code was correct already (exactly yours shown above).  Problem was that when you add the "args" line to the code it sends the args you entered along with 2 others: "__name:=FOO1" and "__log:= ...".  I had code in the other files which verified correct # of args.

**Comment by [vbplaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/15116/vbplaya/) on 2014-08-07**:
My code accounted for too few and too many args ... so I thought it was exiting because it had 0 args when it was actually because of too many.

**Comment by [vbplaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/15116/vbplaya/) on 2014-08-07**:
I finally figured out how to put the code in without messing up when using the greater than or less than symbols!  That took a while ... sadly.  Thanks for your help.  Do you have any idea on the second part of my question about how I can assign the args by means of the rosparam yaml file I load?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-07**:
I think @bvbdort 's answer does a good job of describing how to set parameters in a launch file and how to retrieve them from C++.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use `param` tag inside `launchfile`

```
<launch>
   <node pkg="foo_pkg " type="foo_node" name="foo_node" output="screen">    
    <param name="num" value="1" />
    <param name="address" value="192.168.10.10" />  
  </node>
 <node pkg="foo_pkg " type="foo_node" name="foo_node" output="screen">    
    <param name="num" value="2" />
    <param name="address" value="192.168.100.20" />  
  </node>    
</launch>
```

Inside your node

```
ros::NodeHandle private_nh_("~");

std::string address_;
int num_;

private_nh_.param("address", address_, "0.0.0.0"); // 0.0.0.0 as default 
private_nh_.param("num", num_, 0); // 0 as default 

// your stuff using params here
```

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-08-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vbplaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/15116/vbplaya/) on 2014-08-07**:
This is how it is done on a regular basis?  It seems excessive to have to go into my source code for each of my packages and add the above code replacing my normal:

       int main (int argc, char *argv[])

       {

             ipAdd = argv[1];

       ...

       }

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-07**:
if you want to use with name this way is useful, if you know the order , you can co with argv[1]... way.

**Comment by [vbplaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/15116/vbplaya/) on 2014-08-07**:
It just seems like if I can call a node from the terminal
rosrun foo_pkg foo_node 1 192.168.100.10 
without any knowledge of internal code parameter names.  I should be able to do it in the launch file that way as well.  Maybe a system call from inside the launch file would work?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-07**:
you should know how the code accessing parameters, if you are using node from other packages check the documentation.

**Comment by [vbplaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/15116/vbplaya/) on 2014-08-07**:
I agree I should know ... and I do.  I just feel that it should be more straight forward approach which doesn't involve changing code to accommodate my launch file.  I found on the ROSwiki "how" to do it but I've got it exactly this way and it isn't working. See next comment (comments are too short)

**Comment by [vbplaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/15116/vbplaya/) on 2014-08-07**:
See http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML
 **Half way down page in "A More Complicated Example"**
comment: Pass args to the listener node

**Comment by [vbplaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/15116/vbplaya/) on 2014-08-07**:
Apparently the way I had it coded originally was correct (see original question).  The reason it was failing was due to it adding a couple args ("__name:" and "__log:").  This caused a problem with my code which looks for the correct number of args.  Thanks for your help.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-07**:
very good finally you fixed it. I thought your node is reading params "num", "address" like the way you mentioned at the end of your question.